# Edit ViewBag based on dropdownlist selected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have some form with dropdownlist, i want when i select that dropdownlist, the value is passed into controller without page reload, and then change that form based on value pased, without page reload too. I have search for reference like ajax, etc, but none works for me. Please help,

I have two action in controller with that view, one to show the form and one to process httppost with that form, do i have to make one more for this?

Thankyou

Comment: what specifically did not work ? If you want to update your form controls without page reload, you need to use ajax.

Comment: can You provide the ajax  code You tried

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use an Ajax:
-It's be better to use MVC API controller. (Read about Api controller)

-If you want to use the controller then add the path to the routing table

Example:

-Your dropdown list onSelection/Change should trigger your JavaScript function.

-Your javaScript function should contain the following:

-(Read about how to pass json Objects around).

```
  var json = { //You will use json to send your selected value to your controller or api

            selectedValue: SelectedValue

        }
     $.post("//Path for controller/FolderName/Controller/MethodName", json, function (data)   {

           //Code after data received

           if(data.success == true){//display message etc)



      });
```

Alternative: 
Create another page with the form and use razor to edit the form.
You could try the $get function in Jquery.
On change event of the drop down you can call a javaScript method to use $get:

Example

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
$YourDiv.html(data); //re-insert the form into the page
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/